# Conditional Formatting for events with times using excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to build a small class schedule with class name days the class happen start time and end time. I have to make sure the classes are different (not 2 accounting classes)

Accounting   |   MW   |   10:30 AM   |   11:50 AM

Economics   |   MW   |   11:00 AM   |   12:30 PM<-- this needs to be formatted    (highlighted, bold, etc.) to warn that overlaps the previous course

English        |   T       |   10:30 AM   |   11:50 AM<-- Doesn't need to be formatted since happens on a different day

Philosophy   |  W   |   10:45 AM 12:15 <--- This needs to be formatted since it overlaps the first course.

This is what i have so far:
'{=IF(MAX(COUNTIF(B62:B65,B62:B65))>1,"not unique",IF(K64=K65,AND(L64<=M65,L65<=M64),"OK"))}

The formula checks to see if the name of courses repeat, if it does it displays "not unique", if it doe not then it checks to see if the days are the same. if the days are the same then it checks to see if the times overlap, if they don't then it says "OK."
I don't know how to check for repeating days when one course its MW and another course is only W (still overlap)
How do i check for overlapping in ALL courses not just 2 at a time.
Thank You

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can break down your problem like this:

1. **"does the name of the course appear more than once?"**  `=IF(COUNTIF($B$62:$B$65,B62)>1,"not unique","OK")` - NOT an array formula, needs to be copied to each row.
2. **"Does the time overlap any other times listed"**

   2a. "does the start time fall between the start and finish times of any of the courses?"  `=COUNTIFS($C$62:$C$66,"<"&C62,$D$62:$D$66,">"&C62)` - NOT an array formula, needs to be copied to each row.

   2b. does the end time afll between start and finish time for any of the courses?" `=COUNTIFS($C$62:$C$66,"<"&D62,$D$62:$D$66,">"&D62)`  - NOT an array formula, needs to be copied to each row.
3. **"do ANY of the DAYs appear in the other lines."**

   This is the most complex one becaue the line "Accounting | MW | 10:30 AM | 11:50 AM" actually represents two separate occurences!! It would be **MUCH BETER** to create a separate sheet which copies the data as described in your question into a one-line-per-day format. And then use that sheet to detect clashes (using "day=day" + "time overlaps"). If that might be an acceptable solution (ie having an extra sheet) for you let me know and I can advise further.

   The other option is to use regular expression to answer a question: "do any of the characters in this string(ie day initials) appear in any of the other lines". I suggest you do this by installing **MOREFUNC addon** (see instructions at the bottom) and using the following formula: `=REGEX.COMP(B63,"["&$B$62&"]")`. The expression basicly says: "do any of the characters in the square brackets (contents of cell B62) appear in cell B63?"

   **NOTE**: how are Tuesday and Thursday differentiated? I am assuming Tuesday=T and Thursday=H (or other one-letter abbreviation). If it uses two-letter abbreviations: TOUGH! find-replace them to be one-letter!

   Solution below uses `REGEX.COMP()` function from morefunc addon

---

**BASIC EXAMPLES** - results for row 62 - as displayed

```
        A           B   C           D           E                   F               G               H               I                   J
    ________________________________________________________________________________________________________
61  ||                                          does start time     does end time   time overlaps?  any of the      time overlaps       do day and time match
                                                overlap with        overlap with                    days match?     AND days match
                                                Row 62?             Row 62?                                         
62  ||  Accounting  MW  10:30 AM    11:50 AM                        
63  ||  Economics   MW  11:00 AM    12:30 PM    FALSE               TRUE            TRUE            TRUE            TRUE                TRUE
64  ||  English     T   10:30 AM    11:50 AM    FALSE               FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE               FALSE
65  ||  Philosophy  W   10:45 AM    12:15 PM    FALSE               TRUE            TRUE            TRUE            TRUE                TRUE
66  ||  OtherCourse F   11:00 AM    11:50 AM    FALSE               FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE               FALSE
```

**BASIC EXAMPLES** - results for row 62 - formulae (times displayed as numbers)

```
        A           B   C           D           E                                           F                                           G               H                                   I               J
    ________________________________________________________________________________________________________
62  ||  Accounting  MW  0.4375      0.49305                     
63  ||  Economics   MW  0.4583      0.52083     =IF(AND($C$62>C63,$C$62<D63),TRUE,FALSE)    =IF(AND($D$62>C63,$D$62<D63),TRUE,FALSE)    =OR(E63,F63)    =REGEX.COMP(B63,"["&$B$62&"]")      =AND(G63,H63)   =AND(OR(IF(AND($C$62>C63,$C$62<D63),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND($D$62>C63,$D$62<D63),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP(B63,"["&$B$62&"]"))
64  ||  English     T   0.4375      0.49305     =IF(AND($C$62>C64,$C$62<D64),TRUE,FALSE)    =IF(AND($D$62>C64,$D$62<D64),TRUE,FALSE)    =OR(E64,F64)    =REGEX.COMP(B64,"["&$B$62&"]")      =AND(G64,H64)   =AND(OR(IF(AND($C$62>C64,$C$62<D64),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND($D$62>C64,$D$62<D64),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP(B64,"["&$B$62&"]"))
65  ||  Philosophy  W   0.4479      0.51041     =IF(AND($C$62>C65,$C$62<D65),TRUE,FALSE)    =IF(AND($D$62>C65,$D$62<D65),TRUE,FALSE)    =OR(E65,F65)    =REGEX.COMP(B65,"["&$B$62&"]")      =AND(G65,H65)   =AND(OR(IF(AND($C$62>C65,$C$62<D65),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND($D$62>C65,$D$62<D65),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP(B65,"["&$B$62&"]"))
66  ||  OtherCourse F   0.4583      0.49305     =IF(AND($C$62>C66,$C$62<D66),TRUE,FALSE)    =IF(AND($D$62>C66,$D$62<D66),TRUE,FALSE)    =OR(E66,F66)    =REGEX.COMP(B66,"["&$B$62&"]")      =AND(G66,H66)   =AND(OR(IF(AND($C$62>C66,$C$62<D66),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND($D$62>C66,$D$62<D66),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP(B66,"["&$B$62&"]"))
```

**FINAL SOLUTION** - valid for all rows.  - as displayed

```
        A           B   C           D           E                                           F                                           G               H                                   I               J
    ________________________________________________________________________________________________________
62  ||  Accounting  MW  10:30 AM    11:50 AM    TRUE
63  ||  Economics   MW  11:00 AM    12:30 PM    TRUE
64  ||  English     T   10:30 AM    11:50 AM    FALSE
65  ||  Philosophy  W   10:45 AM    12:15 PM    TRUE
66  ||  OtherCourse F   11:00 AM    11:50 AM    FALSE
```

**FINAL SOLUTION** - valid for all rows.  - formulae

```
        A           B   C           D           E                                           F                                           G               H                                   I               J
    ________________________________________________________________________________________________________
62  ||  Accounting  MW  10:30 AM    11:50 AM    "=OR(
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$62,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$62),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$62,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$62),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$62,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$63,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$63),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$63,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$63),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$63,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$64,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$64),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$64,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$64),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$64,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$65,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$65),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$65,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$65),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$65,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$66,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$66),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$66,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$66),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$66,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]""))
                                                    )"
63  ||  Economics   MW  11:00 AM    12:30 PM    "=OR(
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$62,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$62),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$62,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$62),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$62,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$63,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$63),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$63,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$63),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$63,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$64,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$64),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$64,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$64),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$64,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$65,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$65),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$65,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$65),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$65,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$66,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$66),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$66,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$66),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$66,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]""))
                                                    )"
64  ||  English     T   10:30 AM    11:50 AM    "=OR(
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$62,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$62),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$62,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$62),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$62,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$63,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$63),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$63,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$63),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$63,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$64,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$64),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$64,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$64),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$64,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$65,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$65),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$65,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$65),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$65,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$66,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$66),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$66,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$66),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$66,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]""))
                                                    )"
65  ||  Philosophy  W   10:45 AM    12:15 PM    "=OR(
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$62,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$62),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$62,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$62),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$62,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$63,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$63),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$63,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$63),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$63,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$64,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$64),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$64,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$64),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$64,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$65,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$65),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$65,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$65),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$65,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$66,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$66),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$66,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$66),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$66,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]""))
                                                    )"
66  ||  OtherCourse F   11:00 AM    11:50 AM    "=OR(
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$62,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$62),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$62,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$62),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$62,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$63,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$63),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$63,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$63),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$63,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$64,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$64),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$64,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$64),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$64,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$65,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$65),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$65,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$65),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$65,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]"")),
                                                    AND(OR(IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))>$C$66,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))<$D$66),TRUE,FALSE),IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))>$C$66,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))<$D$66),TRUE,FALSE)),REGEX.COMP($B$66,""[""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))&""]""))
                                                    )"
```

---

**MOREFUNC ADDON**

- here is the last working [download link](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=14922) I found
- here is a good [installation walk-through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAofPm4LCRc#t=92)

Answer (score 0):

Go to "new formatting rule" and choose the last option (in Excel 2010), which is "use a formula to determine which cells to format").  Then you should be able to write an Excel function that would test true (and format the cells) if it meets the criteria.